# Track FCM token of a user who have opened a push notification

Tags: push-notification, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

Let's say I sent a notification to all of my app users using FCM. How can I track down all the users who have opened the notification?

In my firestore database, I have FCM tokens stored in each users' user document.

I was thinking maybe I can accomplish this by exporting the FCM related analytics data to BigQuery, but I found this page and I guess the FCM token is not exported to BigQuery.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery

Can instance_id or other information that is dumped to BigQuery somehow be associated to FCM token?
If not, how can I track down precisely which one of my users have opened my notification that I sent to every user of my app?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, FCM token is not exported to BigQuery. What you can think about is implement this by yourself using [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/). For example, post the token from Android application to Cloud Functions, which can pass it to BigQuery.

You can also use automatically sending the FCM message data to [BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#bigquery_data_export). It is kind of tricky one, because as a first you need to send a message to clients in order to get their token (`instance_id`).

You may refer to the reference of the fields in the exported data in BigQuery at the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#what-data-exported).

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: So if I export FCM token to BigQuery using cloud functions, how do I tie that token to each notification? What I want to do is I want to know who opened a notification I sent.